# DOM events are not fired after disabling element in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events

I am developing a simple game where the user clicks the 'Start' button, the button is disabled and after that user performs some actions on the canvas using an arrow keyboard. It works as expected in Chrome but I observed a strange behaviour in Firefox. Namely, after disabling the button, 'keydown' events are not fired on the page until I click somewhere on it. It looks like after disabling the button, the page loses focus or something.

Is this behavior according to specifications, or is it a Firefox DOM event dispatching bug?

Firefox 64.0, Ubuntu

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const canva = document.querySelector('.canva');
const doc = document.documentElement;

doc.addEventListener('keydown', evt => {
  canva.innerHTML = evt.key;
});

button.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  button.disabled = true;
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #F4511E;
}

button {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.canva {
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;

  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bald;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Lost events</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <button>Start</button>
  <div class="canva"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which version of firefox you are using as it's working as expected on macOS firefox ( v64.0)

Comment: Reproducible in Firefox Dev Edition 65.0b4

Comment: @front_end_dev, Firefox 64.0, Ubuntu

Comment: Can't repro on 65 macOS. What if you listen directly on `document`? What gets output  when you log `document.activeElement`?

Comment: @Kaiido, thanks. `document.activeElement` is `<body>` after page load. And after button click and disabling: on Chrome - it is still `<body>`, but on Firefox it is disabled button. So it looks like disabled button is like a black hole for DOM events) `document.activeElement.blur()` makes `<body>` active again and solves the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Button gets focus and becomes `document.activeElement` after click. After disablind it is automatically `blur()`-ed in Chrome, but in Firefox it continues to be `activeElement` and eats events like a black hole. So, it is necessary to explicitly call `document.activeElement.blur()` after disabling `activeElement`

Thanks to @Kaiido for his comment

There is an issue in Firefox bugtracker about that
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=706773